# rspec says custom path are undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I have this entry in my routes file

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    get "/get_info/:pone/:ptwo", to: "whatever#getInfo", as: "get_info"
  end
end
```

and this in my spec file

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "controller test", type: :request do
  describe "get_info" do
    it "gets info" do
      get get_info_path(55,55)
      expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    end
  end
end
```

When I run my spec file, it says `undefined local variable or method 'get_info_path'`

all of the answers I've found so far say that adding `config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` to spec_helper.rb will resolve this issue, but it isn't solving my problem

here is my spec_helper:

```
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups

end
```

and here's my rails_helper:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec', 'support', '**', '*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  config.include ControllerSpecHelpers, :type => :controller
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
end
```

Comment: Did you add the `config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` to the `RSpec.configure do |config|` block?

Comment: that'd be an affirmative

Comment: What does your spec_helper.rb looks like?

Comment: Can you paste your `rake routes` and your `spec_helper.rb` as @isim suggested?

Comment: added spec_helper and rails_helper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `$ rake routes`, you'll see that you'd get the following output given your configured route:

```
api_v1_get_info GET /api/v1/get_info/:pone/:ptwo(.:format)  api/v1/whatever#getInfo
```

So, the path you would need to use in your specs is `api_v1_get_info_path` and not `get_info_path`.

Your route

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    get "/get_info/:pone/:ptwo", to: "whatever#getInfo", as: "get_info"
  end
end
```

is pretty much the equivalent of

```
scope :api, module: :api, as: :api do
  scope :v1, module: :v1, as: :v1 do
    get "/get_info/:pone/:ptwo", to: "whatever#getInfo", as: "get_info"
  end
end
```

So, if you would like to use a `get_info_path` helper to route to the same controller with the same path, you can change your route to remove the `as` option:

```
scope :api, module: :api do
  scope :v1, module: :v1 do
    get "/get_info/:pone/:ptwo", to: "whatever#getInfo", as: "get_info"
  end
end
```

Which, if you run `$rake routes`, will give you:

```
get_info GET /api/v1/get_info/:pone/:ptwo(.:format)  api/v1/whatever#getInfo
```

For more information about the usage `scope` and `module`, check out the [controller namespaces and routing section of the Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing).

Comment: That was exactly it, thank you. I didn't know namespacing also changed the custom route naming